# How to use EventToCommand (Catel) in UWP apps

Tags: xaml, mvvm, catel, eventtocommand

The code below under the Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight works like a charm

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
<i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
    <interactivity:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ApplyCommand}"
                       DisableAssociatedObjectOnCannotExecute="True"
                                  PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
</i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Is exist any way to work under Universal Application (Windows 10)?

Comment: I suggest you change the title, this has actually nothing to do with Catel but with UWP. A suggestions would be "How to use EventToCommand in UWP apps"

Answer (score 2):

EventToCommand is not available in UWP (WinRT). You can (or should) use this instead:

1.Install the Behaviors sdk via NuGet

2.Use this code

```
<Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
  <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Loaded">
       <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ApplyCommand}" />
  </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
</Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```